# Spring AMQP Consumer stopped receiving messages

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-amqp

I am using Spring AMQP. 
My Consumer is stopped listening messages, however there is no exception in logs and I could not see any deadlock on thread dump.
I have two servers which are listening to 10 queues.

Everything was working fine when cache-mode of rabbit:connection-factory was 'CONNECTION'.
But when I changed it to 'CHANNEL' this issue started appearing frequently.

From the rabbitMQ UI console I can see there is one unacknowledged messages. (Acknowledge mode is 'AUTO').
It looks to me that client could not send acknowledgement back to the server.

I can see following in my thread dump

```
"" prio=10 tid=0x00007f5f3823c000 nid=0x5faa waiting on condition [0x00007f5f847e2000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000007b83a5260> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:226)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2082)
    at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.poll(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:467)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer.nextMessage(BlockingQueueConsumer.java:359)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1000)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:989)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$700(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:82)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1103)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Which version of Spring AMQP do you use? How about to upgrade to the latest: http://projects.spring.io/spring-amqp/ ? I can't recall, but seems for me we have fixed some deadlock there recently...

Comment: @ArtemBilan I am using 1.6.1

Comment: Ok. Good . Can you come up with some test-case or simple Spring Boot application to play from our side?

Comment: @ArtemBilan my channel-cache-size is 40. It appears to me that acknowledgement from client is not sent. I am wondering why RabbitMQ client can't open another channel and start processing other messages.

Comment: Well, it can't do acknowledgement, nor  open another channel because it has some deadlock according to your logs. That's why I would like to have some test-case from you to figure out what we have missed.